# In Mass Effect, where is the small station that sells special items?

Tags: mass-effect

I beat Mass Effect on the Xbox a few years ago, and now I'm replaying it on PC so I can carry my save over to ME2. I remember from my previous playthrough that I found a little station with a guy on it who sells really powerful, expensive, high-level items. I remember when I landed on the station, he was under attack, and once you kill the guys attacking him, he'll sell to you.

Unfortunately, I can't remember where this station is. I'm about to head to Ilos, and I can't remember if you can free-roam any more after that, so I'd like to find this station. Neither the station nor the merchant are mentioned on the ME wiki. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I want to say he was a supplier for some group, or he was smuggling, or something like that, and because you help him he agrees to let you buy some of his items.

Comment: I may have to try booting up my xbox when I get home to see if I can find it. This is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That sounds an awful lot like you've confused [Yavin Station](http://www.gamebanshee.com/starwarskotor/locations/yavinspacestation.php) from the original Knights of the Old Republic (also a Bioware game, and also released on Xbox) with Mass Effect?

Comment: good call, that fits the bill very well

Comment: Oh my god, you're right! The second I saw that map I recognized it, and the description confirmed it. Not sure how I got it confused with Xbox ME1, as I never played KOTOR on the Xbox. Thank you, I had given up on figuring out where that memory came from!

Answer (score 3):

The only thing I can think of that comes close is the [Pinncale Station](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Pinnacle_Station) DLC.  Other than that, the best equipment/gear you can buy in the game is usually from the spectre shop on the citadel.

And no, once you reach Ilos you will be unable to free roam.

Comment: I know that wasn't it. This was before Pinnacle Station was released, I believe, and besides, I don't have any of the DLC. The station had a small airlock section, and then a longer area where the one station occupant is. He had unusual mods, ones which may be unique.

Comment: @SaintWacko then I don't know since I've never played the xbox version.  I definitely don't remember any such shop in the PC version

Comment: I can't imagine that they would have removed it from the PC version. I'll have to see if I can find any of the mods I got from it on my xbox save.